# Krull's theorem applied to vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This feels like a silly question that has been bugging me.

Suppose $X$ is a "nice" proper curve over an algebraically closed field. Let $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{L}'$ be line  bundles over $X$ of non-zero degrees $m$ and $n$ respectively. Assume $m\ne n$. Then: $$\oplus_{i=1}^4 \mathcal{O}_X \cong (\mathcal{L}\oplus \mathcal{L}') (\mathcal{L}\oplus \mathcal{L}')^{\vee}.$$

Which, on rewriting we get

$$\oplus_{i=1}^4 \mathcal{O}_X\cong  \mathcal{O}_X \oplus \mathcal{O}_X \oplus (\mathcal{L}\otimes\mathcal{L}'^\vee) \oplus (\mathcal{L}^\vee\otimes\mathcal{L}').$$

Now, [Atiyah's paper](https://eudml.org/doc/86907) shows that vector bundles have a unique decomposition, so $(\mathcal{L}\otimes\mathcal{L}'^\vee)$ and $(\mathcal{L}^\vee\otimes\mathcal{L}')$ must be trivial line bundles, which is clearly wrong because we started with different degrees.

Where have I messed up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not true that the vector bundle $(\mathcal L\oplus\mathcal L')\otimes(\mathcal L\oplus\mathcal L')^\vee$ is trivial. For example, take $X=\mathbb P^1,m=1,n=-1$, then LHS and RHS have different $h^0$.

Comment: How silly of me. Thanks a lot!